# SQL Server - Conditional OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way in SQL Server 2008 do to something like below?

Can the outer applied(joined) table to be specified based on a condition?

```
declare @bGetExtendedInfo bit
set @bGetExtendedInfo = 1

declare @param nvarchar(24)
set @param = 'CO-02-BBB'

select t1.*, t2.ID
from t1
outer apply (
              case when @bGetExtendedInfo= 0 
                  then (select 0) as ID  /* dummy value */
                  /*really expensive query trying to avoid when extended info is not needed*/
                  else (select top 1 ID from tbl1 where tbl1.code = @param)
              end
             ) t2
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon and JW for your answer. I want to accept both as answers as it really helped me learn a nice technique. However, I realize I did not provide enough info on what I was trying to do. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can readily do this with just a join:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM   t1 cross join
       (SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT top 1 tb10.*, 0 as bCcond src FROM tb10 
              UNION ALL
              SELECT top 1 tb11.*, 1 as bCcond src FROM tb11
             ) t
        WHERE @bCond = bCcond
       ) t2
```

Doing the `top` before the `union all` should also help the optimizer produce a better query plan, in the event that the tables are really complex joins.

Also, doing `top` without an `order by` is generally frowned upon.  It can return different rows with different invocations, but the rows are not guaranteed to be random.

Comment: Do you mean top _without_ an order by rather than with?

Comment: @Bridge . . . Thank you for reading what I mean instead of what I write.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try,

```
DECLARE @bCond BIT
SET @bCond = 1

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM   t1 OUTER APPLY
             (
                SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT *, 'a' src FROM tb10
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT *, 'b' src FROM tb11
                    )s
                WHERE   src = CASE WHEN @bCond = 0 THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END
             ) t2
```

Comment: Thank you JW. Very nice aproach. I realized that I was not very clear on what I was trying to do. I was trying to avoid an expensive query from being executed when I didn't need to get the fields from the big table. Please see my edited question.